# How to fix the error Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Member' object is not iterable

Tags: python, command, bots, discord

m I'm trying create a command that Zalgofyes a members user name when they use the command but I'm having trouble getting it working I'm using the python library zalgo_text here is the code

````
async def fmsu(ctx):
     await ctx.author.edit(nick=zalgo.zalgo().zalgofy(ctx.author)),
     await ctx.send("Your username has been Zalgofyed {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message))``` 

When I use the command I get this error discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Member' object is not iterable
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the name of `ctx.author`.

At the moment you are asking something that is supposed to handle strings to handle a member object..

Solution: `ctx.author.name`. I still highly recommend you check out the API docs
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#user to see why this didn't work and might help you for any future problems.